# Adding an icon to an ASP.NET Button with CSS3

Tags: asp.net, css

I have found a very nice set of buttons that I would like to use in an ASP.NET Web App here:

http://www.red-team-design.com/just-another-awesome-css3-buttons#comment-168128

They designed those buttons using pure CSS3. If I use the CSS classes they have there and set my `<asp:button CssClass = "button">`, it will just take some of the elements from that CSS class (background color, border style, etc.), but it won't use the icons.

I know it can't use any of the icons because I can't use CSS subclasses (e.g. `<asp:button CssClass = "button add">`... please correct me if there is a way to do so), so I was willing to create a different class for each button.

For instance, for the button with the plus icon, which I named `.buttonPlus`, I moved the CSS attribute `content: "\271A";` (that is the + icon) to be part of its `.buttonPlus:before` selector, and still it won't render the icon. If I use the button as they suggest (using an HTML link):

`<a href="" class="button add">Add</a>`

The button gets rendered with the icon, as it should. Of course, I wan't to use my ASP.NET server side button for obvious reasons.

If anyone has good experience with both CSS3 and ASP.NET, please let me know how to go about this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use a `LinkButton` server control instead of a `Button`.

That will ensure an html anchor tag instead of a button tag in the rendered html.

```
<asp:LinkButton CssClass="button" />
```

Comment: This, indeed works! I was looking for so many workarounds, and didn't think the simple Linkbutton element would do it for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You might want to use linkbutton which will be rendered as anchor and applying respective class should give you the same output as shown in that link.